# How to use passportjs without express or how to use middle-ware without express?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

I am trying to use passportjs http://passportjs.org/ for session handling. The problem being that anything that I could find on the internet says that I have to use expressjs http://expressjs.com/ if I want to use passportjs.

I am a learner of nodejs. So I prefer implementing my own routers. I prefer to use mustache https://mustache.github.io/ for template.

The above two things I can't do using expressjs as it doesn't have support mustache, and like I said I prefer implementing my own routing.

But most of all I like to work without a framework mainly because I am still a learner. Once I have learned to a satisfactory level, I may switch to using a framework but for the time being I want to work without a framework.

Can you please tell me if I can use passportjs without express (All my searches on google tends to give me the answer NO)?

Another query that is in my mind is that how can I make my own middle-wares and use them in my nodejs server without using a framework like express or connect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What web application module are you using if not express?

Comment: @BenDiamant Like I said I am not using any framework and doing everything from scratch. If you want to take a look https://github.com/ishanatmuz/cgapiserver/tree/localLogin I have tried to do cookie handling myself, since I couldn't figure out how to use passportjs.

Comment: i need to use passport within an AWS lambda function. I dont have express in there. Just need to authenticate creds against a saml idp